# .NET Web API Serve PDF File

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, pdf, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to serve a PDF file as a ContentResult in my web API. I have tried to return the PDF payload as an `<iframe>` and as an `<object>`. However, the base64 encoded data string is too long I believe and neither one loads the PDF file. I want to return a PDF file without forcing users to download it as a separate file and open it in a PDF viewer and instead user the browser's default PDF viewer, hence the `<iframe>`.

The default from what I gather is 2k characters or 2MB.

The following is my code for return the ContentResult:

```cs
return new ContentResult
{
  ContentType = "text/html",
  StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,

  // <iframe> version
  Content = $"<iframe title='PDF Viewer Frame' src='{{data:application/pdf;base64,{myFile}}}' height='600px' width='100%'/>"

  // <object> version
  Content = $"<object type='application/pdf' data='data:application/pdf;base64,{myFile}' height='600' width='600'><object/>"
};
```

I am not sure if this is the best approach to serving a PDF by API call or if there is a better way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does a file download with Content-Disposition: inline work?

Comment: I did look up Content-Disposition but as a ContentResult, it appears there is no Content-Disposition field as it might treat the result as inline by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with React and had a syntax error when I moved the call over to my API. The following should work and there was no issue.

```cs
return new ContentResult
{
  ContentType = "text/html",
  StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,

  // <iframe> version
  Content = $"<iframe title='PDF Viewer Frame' src='data:application/pdf;base64,{myFile}' height='600px' width='100%'/>"

  // <object> version
  Content = $"<object type='application/pdf' data='data:application/pdf;base64,{myFile}' height='600' width='600'><object/>"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it possible use FileContentResult instead ContentResult

```
//read file to byte array, by example from disk
var fileBytes=File.ReadAllBytes(youFileName);

return new FileContentResult(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = "fileName" };
```

or

```
// inline
Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline");
return File(fileBytes, "application/pdf");
```